# Show binary pdf as link on website

Tags: php, database, variables, pdf, binary

I've got a variable that gets the pdf as a binary file into the website

```
<?=$calculationData->PDF_file?>
```

How do I show the pdf as a link, instead of binary text?
Note: I'm a newbie at this and don't know a lot about php! :-)

Comment: what do you mean by  pdf as a link

Comment: you can put relative path of the file to the website，everytime people click this link，they will download the pdf file.

Comment: Downloadable link. like <a href="mypdf.pdf">my pdf</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $calculationData is an object from a database and the PDF content is stored there as binary data. Then you can do something like this:

Link to a PHP file that loads the content and sends it to the browser.

```
<a href="show_pdf.php?id=555">
```

Where id is the id of your calculationData somewhere in the database in this example. You need something to identify it.

**show_pdf.php:**

```
<?php
/* load your calculation data here ... */

header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='mywhateverfile.pdf'");

echo $calculationData->PDF_file;
exit();
```

In that way you can send the binary data to the browser and telling it with the correct headers, what to do with that data.

Comment: Okay, I got that know!
$calculationData->PDF_file; is defined in an azure database. A file called "class.Connect.php" is calling all the functions. How do I "call" this file, so it reads $calculationData->PDF_file correctly?

Comment: You can include the file, for example with `include_once 'class.Connect.php';` (and the right path). But I doubt that will do the trick. It's obviously a class, so you need to generate the object and then probably use the right methods.

Comment: Ah okay, I'll try and see if I can figure it out. So far so good. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and it could be, that the file content in the database is base64 encoded. So you would do something like `echo base64_decode($calculationData->PDF_file);`